# React: How can I use {props.children} in two layouts of the App structure

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have created a system in React where every page checks if the user is authenticated which means he is logged in.

But I have two different layouts for my pages and they both use`{props.children}`which results in just an empty page when any of the two layouts gets loaded and the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
CustomLayout
.../src/containers/Layout.js:129
  126 |     </div>
  127 |   </div>
  128 | </div>
> 129 | <div
      | ^  130 |   className={
  131 |     active ? 'main-content-wrapper' : 'main-content-wrapper-collapsed'
  132 |   }
```

My App.js structure looks like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className='App'>
          <CheckAuthenticated>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/login' exact component={NormalLoginForm} />
              <Route path='/signup' exact component={SignUp} />
              <Route path='/reset_password' exact component={ResetPassword} />
              <Route path='/password/reset/confirm/:uid/:token' component={ResetPasswordConfirm} />
              <Route path='/activate/:uid/token' component={Activate} />
            </Switch>
          </CheckAuthenticated>
          <CustomLayout>
            <Navbar />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <Route path='/profile' exact component={Profile} />
              </Switch>
            </CustomLayout>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

The `<CheckAuthenticated>` just holds the useEffect function that checks if the user is authenticated and doesn`t give a JSX layout for the children:

```
const CheckAuthenticated = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                await props.checkAuthenticated();
                await props.load_user();
            } catch (err) {

            }
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(null, { checkAuthenticated, load_user })(CheckAuthenticated);
```

The `<CustomLayout>` also holds the useEffect function that checks if the user is authenticated  but also has JSX which is the layout for the dashboard of the app and also has a {props.children} part:
(this is the small part with {props.children})

```
      <div className={ active ? 'main-content-wrapper' : 'main-content-wrapper-collapsed' }>
        {props.children}
      </div>
```

Is it not possible to use {props.children} two times in the app structure and is there a solution so that every page still checks for authentification but the app still has two different layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did U pass a "props"?
it looks like your  component just not receiving props

```
const CustomLayout = () => (...)
to
const CustomLayout = (props) => (...)
```

You can use `{props.children}` across all the React application without any limitations.

Comment: You are right, my component was `const CustomLayout = ( { props, isAuthenticated }) =>` but I fixed it now, thanks for the help.